# PLS_INTEGER vs BINARY_INTEGER in associative array

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

What is the difference in index by PLS_INTEGER vs BINARY_INTEGER vs VARCHAR2 in associative array oracle plsql? I understood from a few sites that the PLS_INTEGER and BINARY_INTEGER no differences from Oracle 9i release. How we can decide which indexing option chosen over other while using associative array to get maximum benefits.

Comment: For a decade or so, `PLS_INTEGER` used to be the fast, recommended one and `BINARY_INTEGER` used to be the obsolete, backward compatibility one, according to the documentation at least, although I don't think anyone ever managed to measure any actual performance difference, and these days they are the same thing. At least using `PLS_INTEGER` shows you've been paying attention, plus it's less to type. As for `index by varchar2`, when you need it, you need it, so I'm not sure what 'maximum benefits' means.

Comment: Thanks, William.